# What does it mean if a drill icon is purple when using VanillaHUD Plus?

Tags: payday-2

Sometimes, when using VanillaHUD Plus, a drill icon will be purple instead of white. This behavior is not necessarily consistent with the skills applied to the drill, though I have observed that it seems to only appear on drills with any autorestart chance (but it does not necessarily appear on autorestart drills). When and why does the purple drill icon appear in VanillaHUD Plus?

[image: Two purple drills on VanillaHUD Plus]

Comment: I did attempt to get a screenshot of one purple and one white drill but couldn't get it unfortunately

Comment: Aren't purple drill those auto-restarting ones?

Comment: @0stone0 Drills with the autorestart skill are sometimes white and sometimes purple

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to an answer on [this Steam Community post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/15/1496741765130292195/) about WolfHUD (which this HUD is based on, "VanillaHUD Plus is a fork of WolfHUD"):

- Blue drills can be upgraded.
- Purple drills auto-restart even when stopped by cops, but it's only visible as host. OP of linked post calls it pink, so apparently settings + display matter. A drill will either auto-restart every time or never, determined when the drill is placed or upgraded by someone with the [relevant skills](https://payday.fandom.com/wiki/Hardware_Expert). It's not a random chance each time the drill breaks. Drills that never restart are white, even when placed with the restart skills.
- White is just a normal drill.